# JavaScript window.innerwidth doesnt work correct

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and wanted to make a simple "hello world" program with changing text based on the width on the screen. If the width of the window (of the index file) is 400 or more pixels, show text, and if the window is smaller then 400px show other text. I do not know why my code does not work. Can somebody please explain this to me, thanks in advance

this is my code (HTML and JavaScript )

HTML =

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JavascriptResponsive</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world </h1>
<script src="Morris.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript =

```
    var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
if (currentWidth > 400) {
    document.write(" <h1>Hello big world </h1>");

}
else if (currentWidth < 400) {
    document.write( "<h1>Hello small world </h1>");
}
```

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: when i resize the screen to whatever size it keeps on displaying "hello big world "

Comment: This is probably because your code isn't listening for any screen changing events. look into something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: well the code will not run again. It is a once and done thing. If you want it to change, you need to listen for resize and not use document.write.

Comment: but i put a else statement on it right? it should change the screen size when it is smaller then 400

Comment: It will go into the else if you resize the browser and refresh the page. It is not going to go and re-evaluate the code. You need to code it to do that. Again the code only runs once when the page is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When JavaScript code is run the variables do not keep updating and running. So you need to write code to detect when things change. So you need to listen to the resize event. So you bind an event listener and you can rerun the code. You also can not use document.write to output the message after the page loads since it will remove all the page content. So you want to update the DOM.

```js
function updateMessage() {
  var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var message = "Hello small world";
  if (currentWidth > 400) {
    message = "Hello big world";
  }
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = message
}

window.addEventListener("load", updateMessage)
window.addEventListener("resize", updateMessage)
```

```html
<h1 id="msg">Hello world </h1>
```

Comment: The other way to do this is a CSS media query and display attributes.