# JavaScript copying 2 of the same scripts with a other ID won't work

Tags: javascript

I made a progressbar using JavaScript and I later added a intersection observer API to let it automatically run.

I now want to have multiple of these progressbars in my website and my teachers at school told me I could better just copy the code multiple times and change the ID (which I disagree with but I do not know how to make multiple prgressbars run by 1 script).

I copied my html 2 times with a other ID-name and changed the ID-name in my JavaScript file and I even put it in a different `<script>` section but only one progressbar works (the 1st one) the second one does not work.

Why doesn't it work? I am currently learning JavaScript so please tell me what I am doing wrong or if there is room for improvement besides my whole script not working for more then once...

my html =

```
div class="progressbars">
        <div class="progress_status">
          <div id="progressbar">
            <p>5%</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="progressbars">
<div class="progress_status">
  <div id="progressbar2">
    <p>5%</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

the CSS for it ( don't think you will need it but just to be sure)

```
#progressbar /*,#progressbar2 ,#progressbar3 ,#progressbar4*/{
  width: 5%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #D8135A;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: white;
}
```

the JavaScript (the first one works, the second one does nothing to my second progressbar)

```
<script>


const progress = document.getElementById('progressbar')


const options = {
  threshold : 1
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(update, options);
observer.observe(progress);

function update() { 
  var element = document.getElementById("progressbar");    
  var width = 5; 
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 30); 
  function scene() { 
    if (width >= 40) { 
      clearInterval(identity); 
    } else { 
      width++;  
      element.style.width = width + '%';  
      element.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%'; 
    } 
  } 
}  
</script>
```

this is the script that I'd like to function on (on my div #progressbar2)

```
<script>
// start js deel 2
const progress = document.getElementById('progressbar2')
//try this for multiple progressbars

const options = {
  threshold : 1
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(update, options);
observer.observe(progress);

function update() { 
  var element = document.getElementById("progressbar2");    
  var width = 5; 
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 30); 
  function scene() { 
    if (width >= 40) { 
      clearInterval(identity); 
    } else { 
      width++;  
      element.style.width = width + '%';  
      element.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%'; 
    } 
  } 
}  

</script>
```

once again I do not know why this doesn't work, I am new to JavaScript.
I tried a lot of different things like getdocumentbyclassname but I couldn't get it to work..

please tell my if this is possible in one script or how I could make it work with more scripts.

https://snapr.pw/i/2cedbe3345.png

Comment: Please go back and review the edits others have done to your previous posts. For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59183979/215552) was edited to make all of the places where i refers to yourself uppercase, and to fix the name of the language to "JavaScript", which is its rightful name. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58744719/215552) was edited to remove "thanks in advance" as [we generally appreciate more time being spent in making the question on topic than on niceities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/194720).

Comment: what do you mean, i have asked a similar question like this yesterday but i did not get a proper answer so i removed and i changed my question to make it more clear..

Comment: I mean proofread. I've now edited your post so that the language is better. Look at the changes I've made. Try not to make the same mistakes again so that others don't have to keep editing your posts.

Comment: Your HTML shows two `div`s with the same id - "progressbar2".  Is this your actual HTML?  If so, this will cause the problem.

Comment: The way the scripts are written, one will essentially redefine the variables and functions from the other, depending on their load order.

Comment: But if i change all the names of the variables in the 2nd script it still doesnt work? @Amy

Comment: @Morris That was *a* issue.  It wasn't *the* issue.